# How to shred an xml input parameter into a table variable

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I am accepting an input parameter of xml type so that i can accept a list of insurance plans on a transaction. I need to take the xml parameter and shred it into a tale variable so that i can process some logic. How can i shred the XML into my table variable.

Here's a script to create a sample table with data in it;

```
/*
CREATE TABLE PlanData(PlanPos INT IDENTITY, PayerDX INT, PlanDX INT, PayPct DECIMAL(6,2))

INSERT PlanData(PayerDX, PlanDX, PayPct)
VALUES(10, 20, 80)
INSERT PlanData(PayerDX, PlanDX, PayPct)
VALUES(25, 50, 10)

drop table PlanData
*/

DECLARE @xmlPlans XML
SET @xmlPlans = (SELECT PlanPos, PayerDX, PlanDX, PayPct
                 FROM PlanData
                 ORDER BY PlanPos
                 FOR XML RAW('plan'), ROOT('plans')
                 )

print CAST(@xmlPlans AS NVARCHAR(max))

/* We must convert the XML passed in containing all of the insurance payer plan 
data into a usable format for the current scoping. */
DECLARE @tblPlans TABLE(PlanPos INT, IPDX INT, IPPDX INT, PayPct decimal(6, 2))   

--   /* Note that the table is built in order from Primary through the last plan */
--   INSERT @tblPlans (PlanPos, IPDX, IPPDX, PayPct)
--   SELECT x.item.value('@PlanPos[1]', 'INT') AS PlanPos,
--      x.item.VALUE('@IPDX[1]', 'INT') AS IPDX,
--      x.item.VALUE('@IPPDX[1]', 'INT') AS IPPDX,
--      x.item.VALUE('@PayPct[1]', 'decimal(6, 2)') AS PayPct
--   FROM @xmlPlans.nodes('//items/item') AS x(item)


   INSERT @tblPlans (PlanPos, IPDX, IPPDX, PayPct)
   SELECT T.plann.value('@PlanPos', 'int') AS PlanPos
      ,T.plann.VALUE('@PayerDX', 'INT') AS IPDX
      ,T.plann.VALUE('@PlanDX', 'INT') AS IPPDX
      ,T.plann.VALUE('@PayPct', 'decimal(6, 2)') AS PayPct
   FROM @xmlPlans.nodes('plans/plan') as T(plann)


---- Attribute-centered XML
--DECLARE @data XML
--SET @data = '<data><customer id="1" name="Allied Industries"/><customer id="2" name="Trades International"/></data>';
--
--DECLARE @tblCust TABLE(id INT, [name] VARCHAR(20))
--
--
---- Using the value() method
--INSERT @tblCust (id, [name])
--SELECT T.customer.value('@id', 'INT') AS customer_id,
--       T.customer.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS customer_name
--FROM @data.nodes('data/customer') AS T(customer);   
--
--SELECT id AS dx, name AS CustName FROM @tblCust



--   SELECT x.item.value('@PlanPos[1]', 'INT') AS PlanPos,
--      x.item.VALUE('@IPDX[1]', 'INT') AS IPDX,
--      x.item.VALUE('@IPPDX[1]', 'INT') AS IPPDX,
--      x.item.VALUE('@PayPct[1]', 'decimal(6, 2)') AS PayPct
--   FROM @xmlPlans.nodes('//items/item') AS x

   SELECT
      p.PlanPos AS PlanPos,
      p.IPDX AS IPDX,
      p.IPPDX AS IPPDX,
      p.PayPct AS PayPct
   FROM @tblPlans p
```

You will also see me attempts at it that are failing.

Thank you,

Brian

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I tried your tables and I get the following output from your `FOR XML RAW.....` statement:

```
<plans>
  <plan PlanPos="1" PayerDX="10" PlanDX="20" PayPct="80.00" />
  <plan PlanPos="2" PayerDX="25" PlanDX="50" PayPct="10.00" />
</plans>
```

Now which of these attributes do you want to put into which of the columns of the table variable?? Your attribute names used in the `x.item.value(...)` statements just didn't match what is really available in the XML result from your `FOR XML` statement.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tblPlans TABLE(PlanPos INT, IPDX INT, IPPDX INT, PayPct decimal(6, 2))   

INSERT @tblPlans (PlanPos, IPDX, IPPDX, PayPct)
  SELECT x.item.value('@PlanPos[1]', 'INT') AS PlanPos,
      x.item.value('@PayerDX[1]', 'INT') AS IPDX,
      x.item.value('@PlanDX[1]', 'INT') AS IPPDX,
      x.item.value('@PayPct[1]', 'decimal(6, 2)') AS PayPct
   FROM @xmlPlans.nodes('//plans/plan') AS x(item)

SELECT * FROM @tblPlans
```

I get this output from that:

```
PlanPos IPDX    IPPDX   PayPct
  1          10      20      80.00
  2          25      50      10.00
```

Or what is it that you're really looking for??

Comment: aha! Another problem in addition to that was that i had the "VALUES" and not "values".......

Comment: Ah, yes - those XQuery functions *are* indeed case-sensitive!